# Mapbox fllyTo freezing

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox

I develop an android application using mapBox and geocoder.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder

I customized the text field of the geocoder plugin.

The principle is that when I type an address in the text field, it must return me 3 results. And when I click on one of the results, the map must move to that point.

The problem is that on Google Chrome for windows this is not a problem. When I test my app on Google Chrome on Android, the card does not move when the android keyboard disappears.

Do you have solutions to offer me?

Thank you in advance for your answers.